# Typecast from Type. Convert to model from Type

Tags: c#, casting

I have a Model that I get the `Type` from. The Model is of `Type` `BasePage`. Can I cast/convert it to the type of `Type`? This page can be of 10 different types so I would really benefit from having a cast/convert from `Type` that works.

```
Type pageType = page.GetType();

//this is what im trying to do but from the Type instead
var newPageOfType = (pageType)pageToCast; //I would usually use this Typecast
```

**Update**
Updated my question with proper example code. All the `pageType` Types derive from the same `BasePage`

Comment: Is there some reason you need to do it off of the pages' type rather than just attempting to cast your `page` object to `SomePageType`?

Comment: Yes, The page is always of the type `BasePage` when it's passed in the method, even tho it has its "origin" type attached to it. So I need to Cast it to the Type in order to get access to the extended properties. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this is by actually doing the cast, and seeing if it succeeds like this:

```
var newPage = page as SomeDerivedPageClass;
if (newPage != null)
{
    // the cast succeeeded, page was actually of the derived type
}
else
    // the passed object wasn't what you were expecting. ignore it,
    // throw an error, log the error, whatever is appropriate.
```

Comment: Thats how I usually would go about it. With 10+ types and more to come it would be really nice to use some cast from `Type`. If that is possible that is?

Comment: possibly, can you post some code that shows how the object is constructed, how it gets passed to your method, and how you want to use it?

Comment: It's just don't have access to that at the moment, I updated my question a bit.

Comment: well, you *can* construct an object off of just the type using Activator.CreateInstance(), but it'll be an empty object and won't be filled out with data from the baser type you've been passed. without more details, there is no way for me or anyone else to help you unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) as long as the `value` parameter implements [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx).

```
Type pageType = page.GetType();
var newPageOfType = Convert.ChangeType(pageToCast, pageType);
```